# wordpress slider not working

Tags: html, wordpress, slider

I have an Html page in which There is a slider. here's the html code

```
<div data-src="images/page1_slide01.jpg">
        <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="camera-text bg01">
              <div class="camera-text_inner">
                <h2>“Black Horse”</h2>
                <h5>by Mark Oswald</h5>
                <p>Ret iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptaum zzelenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Typi non habent claritatem insita</p>
                <a class="btn" href="#">More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I am trying to convert this page into wordpress.

```
<div data-src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/page1_slide01.jpg">
        <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="camera-text bg01">
              <div class="camera-text_inner">
                <h2>“Black Horse”</h2>
                <h5>by Mark Oswald</h5>
                <p>Ret iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptaum zzelenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Typi non habent claritatem insita</p>
                <a class="btn" href="#">More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

But my slider is not working with none images
Please Help me to make my slider working.

Also in source code image paths are showing correctly with display none.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
bloginfo('template_url')
```

To

```
echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use It 
`<div data-src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/images/page1_slide01.jpg">`